# Problems creating cookies in a WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I am trying to create some functionality in a WordPress site that will create a cookie when a user visits a location page that stores the city of the location page they have visited. However I am getting an error from WordPress that I cannot modify header information. I included the below function in my `functions.php` file:

```
function set_city_cookie($city) { 

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['city_cookie'])) {

    // set a cookie 
    setcookie('city_cookie', $city, time()+30);
     $last_city=$_COOKIE['city_cookie'];
        return $last_city;
    }

    } 
    add_action('init', 'set_city_cookie');
```

I then called the function in my `single-locations.php` like this:

```
set_city_cookie($city);
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are sent in the HTTP response header. Since the HTML content already started, you cannot go back to the header and add the cookie. That's why you're having an error like : [How to fix “Headers already sent” error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

From http://php.net/setcookie:

> **setcookie()** defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent ***before*** any output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including `<html>` and `<head>` tags as well as any whitespace.

You should call your `set_city_cookie($city);` before any HTML output :

```
<?php

set_city_cookie($city); 
...

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: This makes sense, when I called the functions in areas above the `html` I no longer got any errors. However my function does still not seem to be actually setting any cookies. When I set to a variable, `var_dump` etc I just get `NULL`

Comment: Did you try to `print_r($_COOKIE);`?

Comment: I just tried that and am just getting an array like this with a bunch of numbers/letters where the dots are: `[has_js] => 1 [wordpress_logged_in_.....] =>....[wp-settings-1] =>....[wp-settings-time-1] =>....` I am guessing it is just WP cookie. I don't see my `city_cookie` in there

Comment: $_COOKIE is set when the page loads, due to the stateless nature of the web. It'll be accessible on a page reload. If you want immediate access, you will have to use your $city variable.